# iOS - Accessing controller view from associated view

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, uiview

I have a `UITableViewController` from which I'm calling another '`.xib`' file which has a `UITextView`. 
From the `UITextView`, a `UIPopoverListView` is created. But `UIPopoverListView` always constricts to the `UITextView`height as this is `subclass`.
 So as a work-around, I created a class method and passed the `UIView` from the main `ViewController` to this.

```
UITextView class :
Header file
+ (void) getUserFriends : (NSString *)string
             getView: (UIView *)view;

Source File

UIView *_view;

+ (void) getUserFriends : (NSString *)string
                 getView: (UIView *)view
  {
     _view = view;

  }


ViewController Class :
Source File -

[ViewController getUserFriends:@"test" getView:self.view];
```

I'm getting the desired result but is this really a good approach? Is there another way to access the view of the controller?

Comment: What you describe isn't superclass / subclass. It's controller / view. Using a class method isn't a great approach. Using an instance delegate relationship would be much better.

Comment: thanks @Wain. I'm new to iOS dev and love learning from guys like you :)